# Stuck in understanding asynchronous behavior of node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I'm learning node js callbacks and asynchronous behavior from [this site.](https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async) From the examples given, I've written following code to understand it better.

```
function callbackTester (callbackFn){
    console.log('From callback tester.');
    callbackFn();
}

function pollingWait(){
    while (true) {}
}

callbackTester(() => {
    console.log('From anonymous function.');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("I'm waiting!");
    }, 500);
    // pollingWait();
});
console.log('I am the last one');
```

Now, when I comment out `pollingWait()` function, it works as expected. It gives following output:

```
From callback tester.
From anonymous function.
I am the last one
I'm waiting!
```

Now when I comment out the `setTimeout` function and add `pollingWait()`,  program goes in infinite loop. I think this is also an expected behavior as node js is single threaded and cannot avoid infinite loops. So how this asynchronous behavior works under the hood?

**How it decides to when to continue execution and when not to? Is it possible to make my own function which acts as asynchronous like `setTimeout`?**

Comment: keyword: event loop javascript

Comment: Okay thanks. That answers my first question. What abut 2nd?

Comment: You can add a delay in your while(true){ } loop that would cause it to jump out and process other things occasionally. ...

Comment: Check out below video for Javascript Event Loop working explaination
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is also an expected behavior as node js is single threaded and cannot avoid infinite loops.

Node.js [isn't single-threaded anymore](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), but there is just one main thread unless you create worker threads.

> So how this asynchronous behavior works under the hood?

Node.js's main thread works on a loop: Your top-level code runs and returns, then any queued action (such as a timer callback) is run and returns, and then the next queued action runs and returns, etc. That's how `setTimeout` works: When it's time for the timer to fire, the event loop sees that and queues a call to the timer callback. Also note that while Node.js has only one main JavaScript thread by default, that doesn't mean Node itself is single-threaded. In particular it may do I/O processing on another internal thread.

> Is it possible to make my own function which acts as asynchronous like setTimeout?

Only by using something that already provides asynchronous behavior and wrapping it. Those would include:

- `setTimeout`
- `setImmediate`
- `process.nextTick`
- A promise's `then` or `catch` callback

At first glance you might think `async` functions do that, but they don't, really: The code in an `async` function runs *synchronously* up until the first time it waits on a promise resolution (or up until it returns). So the asynchronousness is really just the same as the last bullet point above: A `then` or `catch` callback.

What you **can't** do (without a worker thread) is busy-wait like your `pollingWait` does, because nothing else can happen on the thread that busy-wait is running on.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing:

```
let done = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  done = true
}, 5);

const eventLoopQueue = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log('event loop');
      resolve();
    })
  );
}

const run = async () => {
  while (!done) {
    console.log('loop');
    await eventLoopQueue();
  }
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```